# Absolute convergence for $\sum_1^n(f(x))^n$ where $f\in C([0,1])$ and $\|f\|_\infty=1$

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-convergence

I am studying for a final exam I have tomorrow and am having trouble solving this practice problem.

Let $f \in C [0, 1]$, such that $\|f\|_\infty =1$, where  $\| \cdot \|_\infty $ denotes the sup-norm. Show that the $\sum_1^n (f(x))^n$ $n\in N$
cannot converge absolutely for all $x\in [0,1]$ (in other words, for at least one $x\in [0,1]$, it does not converge absolutely).

I am not 100% sure what the correct answer would be but this is what I have so far:

Assume the statement is false. let $f(x)=x$ since $f(x)=x$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ with $\|f(x)=x\|_ \infty = 1$. Then $\lim \sum_1^n (f(x))^n$ diverges when $x=1$ and converges when $x<1$ by comparison with geometric sereis. But this is a contradition thus proving the above statement

Would this be correct? Any and all help with this problem is much appreciated

Comment: Recall the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem), and note that $|f|$ is continuous over $[0,1]$. Then $\exists c \in [0,1]$ s.t. $|f(c)| = 1$, and clearly the above sum diverges for this $c$.

Comment: Would the following proof be correct then: Assume the statement is false. let f(x)=x since f(x)=x is continuous on [0,1] with $||f(x)=x||_ \infty $ = 1. Then Lim $\sum1^n$ (f(x))$^n$ diverges when x=1 and converges when x<1 by comparison with geometric sereis. But this is a contradition thus proving the above statement

Comment: Your notation $\sum_1^n (f(x))^n$ seems rather confused. Did you mean $\displaystyle\underbrace{ (f(x))^n + \cdots + (f(x))^n}_{n \text{ terms}} \text{ ?}$ with the same exponent, $n$, in every term? If not, you shouldn't use the same letter, $n$, for two different things.

Comment: I made a mistake on my above comment. It should be 

Assume the statement is false. let $f(x)=x$ since $f(x)=x$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ with $\|f(x)=x\|_ \infty = 1$. Then $\lim \sum_1^n (f(x))^n$ diverges when $x=1$ and converges when $x<1$ by comparison with geometric sereis. But this is a contradition thus proving the above statement

Comment: But Yes that is what I meant. Its not confused it is exactly as the problem was written

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists $x_0$ such that $|f(x_0)|=1$. Done since $\sum_n 1$ and $\sum_n(-1)^n$ does not converge. Since $f$ is continue, $|f|$ is continue, so there exists $x_0$ such that $|f(x_0)|=sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|=1$ since the domain of $|f|$ is compact. done.